# how to resolve this insurance company database

Tags: database-design

Company offers 3 types of personal motor insurance to vehicle owners. It
includes the third party insurance, fire and theft, and comprehensive cover. All vehicle
owners need to purchase a motor insurance which covers their vehicles, be it a motorcycle, a
car, or a lorry, in case of accidents or thefts. All motor insurance is identified by a unique
policy number, date of purchase, date of expiry, coverage amount, premium amount and
type of insurance, vehicle identification and owner identification. The third party insurance
covers the liabilities to third party for injury, death and damage, while fire and theft covers
an additional loss or damage to own vehicle due to accidental fire or theft. Lastly, the
comprehensive insurance will cover all components of the previous two plus damage to own
vehicle due to accident.

[image]

Is this correct?if not how can I modify it?

Comment: Have you tried anything, i.e. worked out any tables that you already figured out? Or are you expecting the community to solve it for you?

Comment: Worked solution...but i m not sure if ok

Comment: I included insurance type in insurance class then made another class and put their insurance covers and policynum

Comment: @DBAStudent Try editing your post with what you've gotten for a design so far and we can go from there.

Comment: @please check now